# Using jQuery Ajax on Facebook App

Tags: ajax, jquery, facebook

I'm working on a Facebook iFrame App and i need to use ajax request to load content from a script on my own server. Is that possible using jquery or it's not allowed because is a cross-domain request?

I know this could be done by using FBJS on a FBML app with the object Ajax(), but i've just noticed on the official docs that soon FBML will be deprecated.

Basically i need to call a url like "http://www.my-server.com/ajax.php" and load the content of the response into a div, or sending some vars to my server reading the response of the operation.

There's any way to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside a Facebook iFrame you can load anything you want, facebook is phasing out FBML and embedding of iFrams apps is not yet implimented.

so you cna make an app and load content from your server, but the app wont be available to add as a tab on your page or profile.

Comment: thanks for the answer! i dont need to add the app on users profile, what i need is to use $ajax from jquery to post asyncronous on my server, and then get back the response. So, if i understand that is possible...

Comment: surely that is possible, even if ajax is not available you can issue a simple server request to post data :)